# Can only Use Library in Routes file

Tags: laravel, include

I've been testing out the [Imagine Library](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) in my Laravel application and have been running the code straight in the Routes file which has worked fine. However, now when I'm trying to use it in a Model or Controller, it can't seem to find the library anymore even though I've included it the same way I did before with `use Imagine\Image\Box;` and `use Imagine\Gd;`. The code is also exactly the same as in the Routes file but I still get `class 'App\Imagine\Gd\Imagine' not found`.

Do I have to do something different when including stuff in a Model or controller?

Comment: That namespace - App\* - that's your namespace for your project.  Isn't the gd image stuff in the vendor dir?

Comment: try using  
use \Imagine\Image\Box instead of  Imagine\Image\Box

Comment: Oh god, you're absolutely right. Rookie misstake. ;) Thanks guys!